# Retrieve first and last values on HighChart

Tags: c#, javascript, highcharts

I am working with [HighCharts](http://www.highcharts.com/), in particular the line graph.

Using an `Aspx` button click I wish to retrieve the values of the `first` and `last` points on the graph.

When I click on a particular point I can retrieve the value like -

```
click: function() {

                    X = Highcharts.dateFormat('%A, %b %e, %Y, %H:%M', this.x);
                    Y = this.y;
                    document.getElementById('MainContent_dateTB').value = X;
                    document.getElementById('MainContent_countTB').value = Y;

                   }
```

Because the graph has a zoom function, this means the first and last point values can be different, so when a user clicks on the Aspx button (not the point on the graph), I need to retrieve the values of the current first and last values on the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try the 'getExtremes' api call.

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Axis.getExtremes()

```
yextremes = chart.yAxis[0].getExtremes();
xextremes = chart.yAxis[0].getExtremes();
yMax = yextremes.dataMax;
xMax = xextremes.dataMax;
yMin = yextremes.dataMin;
xMin = xextremes.dataMin;
```

Once you have the min/max x value, you can look through your series data looking for the first/last point within that range.

Comment: That is useful however perhaps I was unclear, its no the min and max values I am after, its the first and last values present on the grid?

Comment: when you have `xMin` and `xMax` you can loop over your points, and compare points x-value.

Comment: Sorry i have just realised you did answer my question, I will try to implement this and mark as correct.